# NSUserDefaults setValue vs setInteger

Tags: objective-c, nsuserdefaults

Worked with `NSUserDefaults` for quite some time, suddenly think of this question.
What is the difference, in terms of precision, correctness & performance, between:

```
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setInteger:1 forKey:@"SOME_KEY"];
```

and

```
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setValue:[NSNumber numberWithInt:1] forKey:@"SOME_KEY"];
```

Comment: because it is an integer the prescision and correctness will be the same. Because NSNumber is an Object you will have more overhead to store it, so setInteger might be more performant. But because you normally don't read and write thousends of user defaults in a short time, this should be not relevant.

Comment: I was about to ask this question for `setValue` vs `setObject` but the comment above and the answer below solve this.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Given `NSUserDefaults` can only hold objects it's more than likely that `setInteger` is implemented using `setObject` in a similar manner to the second piece of code.

Using `setValue` employs Key-Value Coding, which does add some overhead, so the first piece of code will be slightly more performant, but nothing will be lost in terms of precision.